# Clone github DEV branch and switch transparently to master once it's released

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, production

At the moment, there is a version 5.4 of some specific product on Github. Version 5.5 should be released within one month which will be the LTS type (Long Term Support).

I need to start a project right now, but logically it's not smart to build a project on 5.4 if 5.5 LTS should be released in following month.

And question is:

How can I keep track with 5.5 LTS which is on the DEV branch at the moment, and once it will be officially available on MASTER branch ?

I would use that branch, without loosing all data already developed by me.

Thank you for your suggestions and tips to correct guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do the following steps to ensure you are in sync with master branch:

1. Create a branch from master which is currently V5.4
2. Continue your development on your newly created branch
3. Once the V5.5 is released, the code will be on master branch
4. Pull the code from master branch to your newly created branch
5. You will not loose your code (You might get some conflicts. Resolve them manually)

Comment: Yeah, this is what I want to do. I thought that there is a second option. Thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah, this is the way you should proceed, no point in waiting for a month till V5.5 is released.